# May i specify a root folder (relative to project root folder) for my package with composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I have a question about composer.json with it's autoload section.

Given:
I have many modules, which is located in {projectRoot}/app/code/VendorName or vendor/vendor-name
Example:

```
app/code/VendorName/ModuleACore
app/code/VendorName/ModuleBCore
app/code/VendorName/ModuleBAddon
app/code/VendorName/ModuleBSubModuleA
app/code/VendorName/ModuleBSubModuleB
app/code/VendorName/ModuleBSubModuleC
app/code/VendorName/ModuleCCore
app/code/VendorName/ModuleCAddon
app/code/VendorName/ModuleCSubModuleA
app/code/VendorName/ModuleCSubModuleB
app/code/VendorName/ModuleCSubModuleC
```

and so on. I can't merge these modules into one coz it is a HUGE EXTENSIBLE THING. Customer can install several modules to meet their need, if their needs some extra functionality -- their can extend the solution with installation of submodule their needs. So, it couldn't be merged...

Each module has it's own composer.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "vendor-name/module-name",
    ...
    "autoload": {
        ...
        "psr-4": {
            "VendorName\\ModuleName\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Also, all of them can be installed in {projectRoot}/vendor/vendor-name/*

So is there a way to build a tree like this with composer.json files of each module:

```
app
  code
    VendorName
      ModuleA
        ModuleACore
        ModuleB
          ModuleBCore
          ModuleBAddon
          ModuleBSubModules
            ModuleBSubModuleA
            ModuleBSubModuleB
            ModuleBSubModuleC
        ModuleC
          ModuleCCore
          ModuleCAddon
          ModuleCSubModules
            ModuleCSubModuleA
            ModuleCSubModuleB
            ModuleCSubModuleC
```

All I have found in google -- is psr-4 of the autoload section, but it specifies only path to package files inside the package folder. Like

```
"VendorName\\ModuleName\\": "src/" // -> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/src/*
                                   // or vendor/vendor-name/module-name/src/*
```

But I need to specify a part of path between VendorName and ModuleName, and I need it to be applicable for both ways of installation: in project sources (app/code/) or vendor (vendor/)

I swear I saw it in one vendor code but I can't remember, how they did it...

Sowwy for kinda vague examples, but NDA :(C

Comment: This completely defeats the point of namespacing, because if you just set your auto-loading to be part of a user’s actual application code, then you have the potential over _overwriting_ user code. Don’t mix user and vendor paths.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wikimedia composer merge Plugin which can go inside a directory search for composer.jsons there and install them in your root vendor.

https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin

With this youn can locale your plugins somewhere else and composer will install them from this point.

maybe this will fix your problem?